# H2O Python: Extract grid search model that with highest AUC on validation data set

Tags: python, h2o

I am building a Random Forest model using a grid search with the H2O Python API. I split the data in train and validation and use *k*-fold cross validation to select the best model in the grid search.

I am able to retrieve the model with the best `MSE` on the training set but I want to retrieve the model with the highest `AUC` on the validation set.

I could code everything in Python but I was wondering whether there is a H2O approach to solve this. Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `g` is your grid object, then:

```
g.sort_by('auc', False);
```

will give you the models ordered by AUC. The 2nd parameter of False means highest AUC will be first. It returns a `H2OTwoDimTable` object, so you can select the first model (the best model, by AUC) that way.

I believe it should be sorting based on scores on the validation set, not training set. However you can specify it explicitly with:

```
g.sort_by('auc(valid=True)', False);
```

Comment: This no longer works in H2O-3.  The new version is: g.get_grid(sort_by='auc',decreasing=True)